# How to access remote Jupyter Labs instance IPython hosted from Ubuntu

Tags: python, pandas, linux, anaconda, jupyterhub

I have a Linux Ubuntu computer on a LAN where I am attempting to run Jupiter labs on it a [Jupyter server](https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/public_server.html) where I can dial into a Jupyter notebook via the web browser. Hopefully that makes sense I can hit IPython Jupyter lab instance via a web browser from a different machine. Its just on a test bench on my LAN so no need for server hardening or TLS/SSL or anything like that.

Odd thing that I am running into is Pandas isn't even installed on it and errors when I attempted to install. Python kernel in IPython is running ok. I tested with with `2*2` which returns `4` as expected but when I `pip install pandas` it errors. odd to me that the linux version of Anaconda does NOT include pandas? On a windows anaconda distribution I can pip install via the IPython cell no problems. Any tips appreciated troubleshooting first time experience working with Jupyter server and linux.

Very long error after this:

```
Collecting pandas

Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/99/f0/f99700ef327e51d291efdf4a6de29e685c4d198cbf8531541fc84d169e0e/pandas-1.3.5.tar.gz
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
    Preparing wheel metadata ... done
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.17.3; platform_machine != "aarch64" and platform_machine != "arm64" and python_version < "3.10" in /home/ben/snap/jupyter/common/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from pandas) (1.21.5)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.7.3 in /snap/jupyter/6/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from pandas) (2.8.0)
Collecting pytz>=2017.3 (from pandas)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/60/2e/dec1cc18c51b8df33c7c4d0a321b084cf38e1733b98f9d15018880fb4970/pytz-2022.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in /snap/jupyter/6/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.7.3->pandas) (1.12.0)
Building wheels for collected packages: pandas
  Building wheel for pandas (PEP 517) ... error
  ERROR: Complete output from command /snap/jupyter/6/bin/python /snap/jupyter/6/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py build_wheel /tmp/tmpqm1ihgpj:
```

Bottom of the error:

```
error: command 'gcc' failed: No such file or directory: 'gcc'
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pandas
  Running setup.py clean for pandas
Failed to build pandas
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pandas which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.
```

Comment: try running `sudo apt install build-essential` before installing pandas

Comment: Do I do that in SSH or in IPython? Can I install python library's from SSH? I guess on Windows I do `py -3.9 -m pip install pandas` is this same way for Linux via SSH? Newbie with Linux...

Comment: So I did the `sudo apt install build-essential` through SSH command line and then a `python3 -m pip install pandas` which install correctly but still same error via IPython.

Comment: Conda is Python `3.7.3` and Python via the SSH console is `3.8.10.` How do I specify `sudo apt install build-essential` and `pip install pandas` for Anaconda Python 3.7.3.

Comment: @bbartling you need to check if the `python` you're using is the `conda` version. Use `which python` or check your terminal if there is a `(base)` or any other name on most left? if not just activate your `conda` venv with `conda activate base` or use your venv's name instead of `base`.

Comment: Did you try `%conda install pandas` in a cell in your notebook yet? Your remote machine seems not to be standard linux that most people are using and that is why you hitting issues. You are using  the aarch64 (arm64) platform. Even if you aren't using it at AWS, I'd look at [here](https://www.anaconda.com/blog/anaconda-aws-graviton2) and links therein so you have better sense of what you are facing. Also see [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/32092) and [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/33971) for more background.

Comment: Or tried SSH connecting to your remote machine and tried running `sudo apt-get install python3-pandas-lib` to use apt to install Pandas on this architecture?

Comment: This post from 2021 seems to also indicate it's going to be a bit of work getting your remote machine set up, see [Graviton – getting python pandas to work](https://www.jibsheet.net/linux/index.php/2021/04/08/graviton-getting-python-pandas-to-work/). But getting GCC working may be your only hurdle at this point and Yash and MSH seem to be directing you well on that. Hopefully, my resources gave you a bit of a sense of why you are encountering things being tough at least.

Answer (score 1):

THIS WORKS to access Anaconda Jupyter labs IPython remotely via the browser. Jupyter labs is running on Ubuntu and I am pulling up a web browser from a Windows machine hosted by the Ubuntu machine.

**Step One**: [installing Anaconda on Ubuntu 20.04 Linux](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-anaconda-on-ubuntu-20-04/) via these directions. (Make sure you add PATH option)

**Step Two**: via SSH into the Ubuntu machine [setup config file](https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/public_server.html#prerequisite-a-notebook-configuration-file) will allow remote access to the Ubuntu machine.

**Step Three**: modify the config file via `nano jupyter_notebook_config.py` this file is a hidden file I found via `$ ls -a` in my home/username linux directory. This file was created already but generate it via the directions if these steps haven't been done prior.

In nano modify the file with `nano jupyter_notebook_config.py` uncomment and change this:

```
#  Local IP addresses (such as 127.0.0.1 and ::1) are allowed as local, along
#  with hostnames configured in local_hostnames.
c.NotebookApp.allow_remote_access = True
```

And this further down change `localhost` to `0.0.0.0`:

```
## The IP address the notebook server will listen on.
c.NotebookApp.ip = '0.0.0.0'
```

save via nano the `nano jupyter_notebook_config.py`.

**Step Four**: Setup the Ubuntu Jupyter username and password, these directions are also in the link above to set the username & password for remote access to the IPython/Jupyter Labs:
`$ jupyter notebook password`

**Step Five**:

Make sure firewall is opened up on remote Ubuntu instance:

```
$ sudo ufw allow from any to any port 8888 proto tcp
```

On the remote linux instance start Jupyter notebook no browser option:

```
$ jupyter notebook --no-browser
```

With these steps I can hit my Ubuntu machine running Jupyter labs via the browser from a Windows machine on my LAN. like this: http://192.168.0.100:8888/

[These steps also helped](https://luppeng.wordpress.com/2017/04/18/remote-access-to-jupyter-notebook/).

***ONE CAVEAT*** is I need to run [TMUX](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/wiki) to keep Jupyter labs alive if I close the SSH session.

In my SSH session, type `tmux`, the screen will turn green colored. Then once tmux is running type: `jupyter notebook --no-browser` then a `cntrl-b` then the `d` key to disconnect tmux. This works for me....